# Passport.js authenticate not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to set up passport for the first time and going with just a single google sign-in option.  I registered with google apis so i have all that setup.  the relavant code is below, but when my app makes the `'/auth/google/'` call it just fails with no response or error message.  I've switched up the configuration a bunch of ways to no avail.  I've also replaced the `passport.authenticate('google')` with an anonymous function with a console.log to double check my web service is operating correctly and it is.  So I know it is getting to the `passport.authenticate('google')`.

```
    // serialize session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
        done(null, obj);
    }); 

      // use google strategy
  passport.use(new googleStrategy({
      clientID: config.google.clientID,
      clientSecret: config.google.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.google.callbackURL,
      scope: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
  }
));


  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());


  app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google'));
  app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/', scope: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds' }), signin);
```

EDIT:
Here is my http request, I'm using angular and this function is tied to a ng-click on a button.

```
$scope.signIn = function () {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/auth/google'}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('success');
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        });
};
```

Those logs return nothing

Comment: You really have no error message? A timeout maybe? How does it fail?

Comment: I haven't been able to catch or get anything back. It just seems to fail with no return of any type.  Maybe have that call configured wrong.  I'll add my ajax code as well just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `done()` inside the middleware for the `GoogleStrategy`

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
       ...
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);

    // Add this
    done(null, profile);//profile contains user information
});
```

Found this [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/google/)